# Export or list system settings that deviate from defaults

Tags: macos, terminal, script, settings, plist

I am looking to generate something similar to [this osx settings script](https://github.com/madhums/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx).  I'm not having any luck finding ways to perform a diff between system defaults and my customized settings.

Anyone know of a command, app, tool, method to generate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might diff the output of `defaults read | awk 'length<200'` on the current installation and a VM. Or convert the plist files to XML first with something like `plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/*.plist`.

It would be difficult to do right though:

- There are probably thousands or tens of thousands of settings that have been changed.
- Settings are stored in different directories like `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost` and `~/Library/Containers/*/Data/Library/Preferences`.
- Many settings are for things like the positions of windows.
- Some applications like Chrome don't even use the defaults system.
- Many settings can't be modified with defaults or PlistBuddy.
- There are a lot of changes between OS X versions.

It's easier to just copy the plist files or recreate settings from GUIs in my opinion.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm really looking for settings like doc, keyboard, shortcut, display, touchpad, and any scripts that have been added to launchctl, etc that aren't in my bash config.  Guess I'll have to be a bit more specific in my search and grab the specific plist files as you mentioned. - Thanks @Lauri